# cloudmade - using the sample code, Marker jumps

Tags: iphone, cloudmade

I've setup a project with cloudmade.
If if tap on a marker and want to drag it, the marker jumps some pixel.

Any suggestions?

Would be great to get some help :)
Thanks!

Comment: Just curious, what's wrong with MapKit?

Comment: no routing. Unfortunately cloudmade has no good documentation yet.

Comment: Their documentation is mostly 404s as of the writing of this comment. Contacting their support, this is a major pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this problem doesn't occur now..